# Как анимировать список при добавлении элемента? (react)

Tags: reactjs, анимация

У меня есть список элементов, в который я из сокетов добавляю элементы по одному. Если пришел элемент, добавляю его первым, а последний при этом удаляю.

Начальное состояние:

- Элемент 1
- Элемент 2
- Элемент 3
- Элемент 4

Состояние после добавления нового элемента Элемент 5:

- Элемент 5
- Элемент 1
- Элемент 2
- Элемент 3

И вот тут я хочу добавить анимацию, чтобы новый элемент плавно появлялся сверху, а все другие плавно уезжали вниз, т.е. как бы прокручивались, а последний уходил в полную прозрачность.

Я пробовала 'react-transition-group' вот так:

Шаблон:

```
<TransitionGroup className="list">
                {
                    list.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <CSSTransition 
                                   key={item.id} 
                                   classNames="list-item" 
                                   timeout={500}>
                                <div key={item.id}>Элемент {item.id}</>
                            </CSSTransition>
                        );
                    })
                 }
</TransitionGroup>
```

Стили:

```
.list-item-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: opacity 500ms, transform 500ms;
}

.list-item-enter-done {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.list-item-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: opacity 500ms, transform 500ms;
}

.list-item-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

Но получается ерунда - так можно управлять только первым и последним элементом списка. 2 и 3 элементы просто тупо перерисовываются на новых местах без плавного перехода.

Подскажите, может есть еще какой подход для такой анимации, что я хочу?